# Docker rmi image no such image error

Tags: centos, docker

I am trying to remove a docker image using `docker rmi <image>` command, but I am getting "No such image" error.

Below is the sequence of commands I executed. Why does it show I have an ubuntu image but does not let me remove it? I am running docker version 18.06.3-ce on CentOS 8.

```
[root@localhost student]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[root@localhost student]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[root@localhost student]# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              18.04               549b9b86cb8d        4 days ago          64.2MB
centos              latest              0f3e07c0138f        2 months ago        220MB
[root@localhost student]# docker rmi ubuntu
Error: No such image: ubuntu
[root@localhost student]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just say `ubuntu` it looks for `ubuntu:latest` while what you have is `ubuntu:18.04`. So try `docker rmi ubuntu:18.04`. You can also delete by ID: `docker rmi 549b9b86cb8d`.

Comment: Thanks xenoid. That worked.